# PHP Array Reformat For Childs

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to convert a list of menu items into a more organized list of menu items. I don't think it much matters but just if you are curious this is a menu array gotten from a WordPress installation. As you can see in the first one all menu items are listed even sub menu items. What I am trying to do is take that original array and convert it with PHP into a more organized array.

I know its going to involve some sort of fancy loop but I have been at a standstill for about an hour now trying to figure this out hopefully someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

> Original Array

```
Array (
    [0] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 13
        [menu_item_parent] => 0
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
    )

    [1] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 14
        [menu_item_parent] => 0
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
    )

    [2] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 15
        [menu_item_parent] => 13
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
    )

    [3] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 16
        [menu_item_parent] => 13
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
    )

    [4] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 17
        [menu_item_parent] => 0
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
    )
)
```

> What I am trying to accomplish

```
Array (

    [0] => Array (
        [ID] => 13
        [menu_item_parent] => 0
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
        [submenu] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [ID] => 15
                [menu_item_parent] => 13
                [url] => http://site.dev/
                [title] => Sample Page
                [target] =>
            )

            [1] => Array (
                [ID] => 16
                [menu_item_parent] => 13
                [url] => http://site.dev/
                [title] => Sample Page
                [target] =>
            )
        )
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [ID] => 14
        [menu_item_parent] => 0
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
    )

    [4] => Array (
        [ID] => 17
        [menu_item_parent] => 0
        [url] => http://site.dev/
        [title] => Sample Page
        [target] =>
    )

)
```

Comment: would be pleasure if you use `var_export()` instead or `print_r()` when outputting the array. - You see var_export can be pasted into code, print_r one must make the keys quoted.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix thats not even the full array ill go do that and edit it one moment

Comment: It's pretty bad when you start noticing  these things, lol, but I can fix it up, you just need to loop and do if parent == 0 then etc, for it.  You could also use the `walker_nav_menu` in wordpress maybe, but that would be harder.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Well the array was only meant to be a guideline so you could understand and I could modify the code or suggestion someone provided to my need.I have tried to do it with that logic but can't come up with a solution.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120419/show-top-level-parent-with-submenu-menu-walker

Comment: Yes, I know, but var_export()'s output can be directly worked with, for example I am to lazy to make the array myself. :-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$new_array = [];
$new_array_ids = [];
$ni = 0;
$sub_array = [];
foreach ($array AS $object) {
    if ($object->menu_item_parent) {
        if (isset($new_array_ids[$object->menu_item_parent])) {
            $new_array[$new_array_ids[$object->menu_item_parent]]['submenu'][] = (array)$object;    
        }
        else {
            $sub_array[] = (array)$object;
        }
    }
    else {
        $new_array[$ni] = (array)$object;
        $new_array[$ni]['submenu'] = [];
        $new_array_ids[$object->ID] = $ni;      
        $ni++;
    }
}

foreach ($sub_array AS $sub) {
    $new_array[$new_array_ids[$sub['menu_item_parent']]]['submenu'][] = $sub;   
}
```

ive not checked this so sorry for possible errors.
Also it will works only if depth of subcategories less then 2

Comment: Issue is the sub category depth could be greater than 2

Comment: so u need some kind of recursive function here. sorry i cant do that cos have no php rightnow to check. w8 for another answer